# MongoDB Group By count occurences of values and output as new field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a **3** Collections ***Assignments, Status, Assignee***.

***Assignments*** Fields : [***_id, status, Assignee***]

***Assignee*** and ***Status*** Fields : [***_id, name***].

There can be many assignments associated with various ***Status*** and ***Assignee*** collections(linked via `_id` field), There is no nesting or complex data.

I need a query for all assignments `ids` where ***Assignees*** are the row, ***Status*** are the Columns, there combined cell is the `count` with ***Total*** counts at the end.

To help you visualize, I am attaching below image. I am new to complex Mongo DB Aggregate framework, kindly guide me to achieve query.

> **Note**: Data in **Status** and **Assignee** collection will be dynamic. Nothing is predetermined in the Query. So, the Rows and Columns are going to grow dynamically in future, If the query is given pagination, then it would be of great help. I cannot write a query with hard coded `status` names like `'pending'`, `'completed'` etc. As data shall grow and existing data may change like `'pending task'`, `'completed work'`.

[image]

Below is my query

```
    db.getCollection('Assignments').aggregate([
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "assignee": "$assignee",
                "statusId": "$statusId"
            },
            "statusCount": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.assignee",
            "statuses": { 
                "$push": { 
                    "statusId": "$_id.statusId",
                    "count": "$statusCount"
                },
            },
            "count": { "$sum": "$statusCount" }
        }
    },
    ]);
```

Below is the output format:

```
    {
    "_id" : "John",
    "statuses" : {
        "statusId" : "Pending",
        "count" : 3.0
    },
    "count" : 3.0
}
{
    "_id" : "Katrina",
    "statuses" : [{
        "statusId" : "Pending",
        "count" : 1.0
    },
    {
        "statusId" : "Completed",
        "count" : 1.0
    },
    {
        "statusId" : "Assigned",
        "count" : 1.0
    }],
    "count" : 3.0
}
{
    "_id" : "Collins",
    "statuses" : {
        "statusId" : "Pending",
        "count" : 4.0
    },
    "count" : 4.0
}
```

Expected Output is:

```
{
    "_id" : "Katrina",
    "Pending" : 1.0,
    "Completed" : 1.0,
    "Assigned" : 1.0,
    "totalCount" : 3.0
}
```

Any Idea on how to many various `statusId` for different `assignee` as keys and not values in single document.

Answer (score 1):

You need another `$group` stage after `$unwind` to count number of status based on statusId string value:

```
{ 
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
         "Pending" : {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ 
                    { "$eq": [ 
                        "$statuses.statusId", 
                        "Pending"
                    ]},
                "$statuses.count",
                0 
                ]
            }
        },
        "Completed" : {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ 
                    { "$eq": [ 
                        "$statuses.statusId", 
                        "Completed"
                    ]},
                "$statuses.count",
                0 
                ]
            }
        },
        "Assigned" : {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ 
                    { "$eq": [ 
                        "$statuses.statusId", 
                        "Assigned"
                    ]},
                "$statuses.count",
                0 
                ]
            }
        },
        "totalCount": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
}
```

The final aggregate command:

```
db.getCollection('Assignments').aggregate([
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "assignee": "$assignee",
                "statusId": "$statusId"
            },
            "statusCount": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.assignee",
            "statuses": { 
                "$push": { 
                    "statusId": "$_id.statusId",
                    "count": "$statusCount"
                },
            },
            "count": { "$sum": "$statusCount" }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$statuses" },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
             "Pending" : {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ 
                        { "$eq": [ 
                            "$statuses.statusId", 
                            "Pending"
                        ]},
                    "$statuses.count",
                    0 
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Completed" : {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ 
                        { "$eq": [ 
                            "$statuses.statusId", 
                            "Completed"
                        ]},
                    "$statuses.count",
                    0 
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Assigned" : {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ 
                        { "$eq": [ 
                            "$statuses.statusId", 
                            "Assigned"
                        ]},
                    "$statuses.count",
                    0 
                    ]
                }
            },
            "totalCount": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }   
]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your time for my question. But you have hard coded the `status` values. I have mentioned in the question that the `status` values and `assignee` values will grow in future. So the above query is not suitable for dynamically growing content.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep statuses as an object so each status is a key/val pair. If that works you do the following

```js
db.getCollection('Assignments').aggregate([
    [
     { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "assignee": "$assignee",
                "statusId": "$statusId"
             },
             "statusCount": { "$sum": 1 }
        },
      },
      { 
        "$group" : { 
            "_id" : "$_id.assignee", 
            "statuses" : { 
                "$push" : { 
                    "k" : "$_id.statusId", // <- "k" as key value important for $arrayToObject Function
                    "v" : "$statusCount" // <- "v" as key value important for $arrayToObject Function
                }
            }, 
            "count" : { 
               "$sum" : "$statusCount"
            }
        }
      }, 
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "_id" : 1.0, 
                "statuses" : { 
                    "$arrayToObject" : "$statuses"
                }, 
                "totalCount" : "$count"
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

This gives you:

```sh
{
    "_id" : "Katrina",
    "statuses": {
      "Pending" : 1.0,
      "Completed" : 1.0,
      "Assigned" : 1.0,
     },
     "totalCount" : 3.0
}
```

A compromise having it one layer deeper but still the shape of statuses you wanted and dynamic with each new statusId added.